# when I input string instead of integer then why it does print 0 and 1 on VScode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, integer

when I input string instead of integer then why it does print 0 and 1 on VScode?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a , b ;
    cout<<"give the value of a and b : ";
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<"a :"<<a<<"b : "<<b;

    return 0;

}
```

Could you please tell me,  does these 0 and 1 are the default input or they are just a garbage ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because when the extraction fails zero is written to the value, as quoted in the [statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) below:

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), **zero is written to value and `failbit` is set**. For signed integers, if extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` (respectively) is written and failbit flag is set. For unsigned integers, if extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is written and `failbit` flag is set.

Thus, when the first extraction `std::cin >> a` fails, `failbit` is set and additionally `a` is set to value `0`. That is why you get `0` for the first output.

But note that since the failbit was set in the first extraction, `b` do not get any value i.e. it has indeterminate value and using that value(which you do in `std::cout<<b`) is **undefined behavior**.